# Chrome fonts are distorted in various way

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've switched from FF to chrome and fonts went crazy. Typically it looks like this:

[image: distorted fonts]

Not even the main post font but also date of the post has uneven kerning. Main problem is facebook, but fonts appear different on SOME websites too. I've tried quite a few solutions, in chrome://flags, Accelerated 2D Canvas, reseting to default settings, switching off every add-on (social fixers etc.)

Comment: What OS? What version of Chrome? What website?

Comment: 63.0.3239.108 64bit, win10

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your fonts are corrupted, try to reinstall them. I found this tutorial on internet how you can do that, enjoy:

1. Click Start -> Run. If you cannot locate the 'Run' item, then click 'Window Key' + 'R'.
2. In the run box, type: c:\windows\fonts (Replace c: with the drive letter where the OS is installed)
3. The fonts window will open. Click 'Alt' + 'F' to activate the menu. Click 'Install New Font' in the menu.
4. In the folders dialog, browse to c:\windows\fonts where c: is the OS drive letter.
5. All fonts would now appear under 'List all fonts'.
6. Click 'Select All' and then click 'Install'.
7. Confirm the windows permission dialog.
8. A replace file dialog would appear. Click on 'Yes' to each and every dialog that appears. This will ensure that fresh entries for fonts are written in the registry. To avoid clicking, press and hold 'Alt' key - then press 'Y' key for every dialog that appears.

Please let me know if this solution doesn't work for you